# How to convert byte[] in to an image in react frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, spring, base64

I am currently working on a project that involves a React frontend and a Spring Boot backend. As part of this project, I need to create events that include both details and flyers. When saving an event, I send the flyer as a file to the backend, where it is converted into a byte array and successfully saved.

Now, I am facing a challenge with displaying the image in the frontend. Specifically, I need to retrieve the byte array from the backend and display the image on the frontend. However, I have been unable to do so thus far.

Here is the code :

```
export default function EditEvent() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const [event, setEvent] = useState({
    eventName: "",
    eventType: "",
    eventLocationType: "",
  });
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(moment());
  const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState(moment());
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(undefined);
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(null);

  const { eventName, eventType, eventLocationType } = event;

  useEffect(() => {
    loadEvent();
  }, []);

  const loadEvent = async (e) => {
    const result = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/event/getEvent/${id}`
    );
    console.log(result.data);
    setEvent(result.data);
    setLocation(result.data.location);
    setStartTime(moment(result.data.startTime, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"));
    setEndTime(moment(result.data.endTime, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"));

    console.log(result.data.eventFlyer)
    const byteArray = result.data.eventFlyer;
    const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "image/png" });
    console.log(blob)
    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(imageUrl);
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      console.log("Image loaded successfully.");
    };
    img.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log("Error loading image.", error);
    };
    img.src = imageUrl;
  };
useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedImage) {
      setImageUrl(URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage));
    }
  }, [selectedImage]);

return(
 <FormLabel disabled={true} align="left" sx={{ paddingBottom: "10px" }}>
          Event Flyer<span>(Optional)</span>
        </FormLabel>
        <div style={{ textAlign: "left", paddingBottom: "30px" }}>
          <input
            accept="image/*"
            type="file"
            id="select-image"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            name="eventFlyer"
            onChange={(e) => setSelectedImage(e.target.files[0])}
          />
          <label htmlFor="select-image">
            <Button component="span" color="inherit">
              <CloudUploadOutlinedIcon sx={{ paddingRight: "10px" }} />
              Click to browse
            </Button>
          </label>
          {imageUrl && selectedImage && (
            <Box mt={2} textAlign="center">
              <div>Image Preview:</div>
              <img src={imageUrl} alt={selectedImage.name} height="100px" />
            </Box>
          )}
        </div>
)
```

So here I'm getting the console.log as ,

`Error loading image. Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: img, currentTarget: img, eventPhase: 2, …}isTrusted: truebubbles: falsecancelBubble: falsecancelable: falsecomposed: falsecurrentTarget: nulldefaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 0returnValue: truesrcElement: nulltarget: nulltimeStamp: 15488456.5type: "error"[[Prototype]]: Event`

I just checked whether the recived byte[] is valid or not using Base64 to image converter. It also shows that byte[] is valid and shows the image correctly.

[image]

**UPDATE**
This the `result.data` showing in the console.
[image]

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or code examples that can help me overcome this issue and display the image correctly. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Pls add the console log for console.log(result.data) to the question.

Comment: I have added the image of my console.

Comment: Based on what is returned, I believe that @AngYC answer below is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON response that you obtained from `fetch` is in Base64 encoding instead of raw byte array. You can consider displaying the image directly instead by prepending the result with `data:image/jpeg;base64,`, sample below:

```js
const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState('');

const loadEvent = async (e) => {
  const result = await axios.get(
    `http://localhost:8080/api/event/getEvent/${id}`
  );
  setImageSrc('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result.data.eventFlyer)
};

<img src={imageSrc} />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a base64, you can display it directly through the image tag.Here is the [reference](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-bouman-rw47kr?file=/src/App.js).